# Linear acceleration sensor values change drastically on tilt change but not on movement

Tags: c#, android, sensors, android-sensors

My LinearAcceleration sensor is acting very weird. Even when I run, stop, run, walk,run,stop,walk... with my phone, sensor gives me very little reaction with below 0.1 values. But when I change my phones angle (tilt) even slightly, values become 3,4 even 5 sometimes while my hand movement occurs. I checked my Accelerometer, it showed aproximate gravitation on all three positive axis ( like 9.7 ), and a little stronger on negative side of them ( like -10 m/s^2 ). So It is probably working. Can't figure out what is wrong.
For example, when I add all the LinearAcceleration sensor values from Y axis to a variable on OnSensorChanged function ( like `v = v + e.Values[ 1 ];` ), it starts with 0 and stays around it, when I change the tilt to 90°, it shows a value like 30 and stays around it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance! Basicaly I sum all the acceleration falls on horizontally on each sensor change, than take average of them every 0.1 second. And if it is bigger than my threshold which is 0.1 m/s^2, I add it to my velocity but as my problem goes, my speed almost doesn't change when I run, stop, run, walk,run,stop,walk... Tho it changes 2-5 points when I change the tilt of the phone in my hand.
Here is my code :

```
    public void OnSensorChanged( SensorEvent e )
    {
        TextView textview2 = FindViewById<TextView>( Resource.Id.textView2 );
        TextView textview1 = FindViewById<TextView>( Resource.Id.textView1 );
        double aci = 0;
        lock( syncLock )
        {
            if( e.Sensor.Type==SensorType.Accelerometer )
            {
                aci = Math.Atan2( e.Values[ 1 ] , e.Values[ 2 ] );
                textview1.Text = "Phone tilt : " + ((int)( ( Math.Atan2( e.Values[ 1 ] , e.Values[ 2 ] ) ) * 180 / Math.PI )).ToString() + " °";
            }
            if( e.Sensor.Type==SensorType.LinearAcceleration )
            {
                ivme = ivme + e.Values[1]* Math.Cos( aci )+e.Values[2]*Math.Sin(aci);
                counta++;
                textview2.Text = "Linear acceleration : " + ((int)( e.Values[ 1 ] * Math.Cos( aci ) + e.Values[ 2 ] * Math.Sin( aci ) )).ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    private void yapbisiler( object sender , ElapsedEventArgs e )
    {
        if( counta != 0 )
        {
            if( Math.Abs( ivme/counta ) > 0.1 )
            {
                velocity = velocity + (ivme/counta) * 0.1;
                RunOnUiThread( () => {
                    TextView textview3 = FindViewById<TextView>( Resource.Id.textView3 );
                    textview3.Text = "Speed : "+ (int)velocity + " meters/second";
                } );
            }
        }
        if( Math.Abs(velocity) >0.1 )
        {
            displacement = displacement + velocity * 0.1; 
        }
        RunOnUiThread( () => {
            TextView textview4 = FindViewById<TextView>( Resource.Id.textView4 );
            textview4.Text = "Displacement : " + (int)displacement + " meters";
        } );
        counta = 0;
        ivme = 0;
    }
```

protected override void OnCreate( Bundle bundle )
{
    base.OnCreate( bundle );

```
t.Interval = 100;
t.Elapsed += yapbisiler;
t.Start();

sensorManager = ( SensorManager )GetSystemService( SensorService );
```

}

Comment: The calculation of the speed, by data from the Accelerometer seems like a good idea at first (I also thought so), but in reality it is a lot more complicated and problematic due to sensor accuracy. I suggest reading [this](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-696.pdf) for a good introduction into the topic and it pit falls. (It helped me a lot to get a more realistic view on the matter)

Answer (score 0):

The interval of 100ms seems large.  Try 1 ms (0.001 second). Be aware
that trying to calculate velocity with an accelerometer is challenging. Check out this [thread.](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22798/can-i-measure-velocity-from-an-accelerometer-how-accurately)